# What is included in the reputation change calculator?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Here is what I saw a few moments ago when clicking on the rep change indicator:

[image]

In the first row, there were only two communities (as shown) which had rep changes today.  Scrolling down in the list, there were no other items shaded in blue (unseen) and nothing in the past 7 days that has an associated number which is not a multiple of 5.  I haven't downvoted recently.
I can understand why "14" might be less than "50" suggested by the highlighting, e.g. if I had clicked this drop-down earlier today.

As an example of the latter, here's a screenshot from slightly later, when only the +10 shows even though the +40 is highlighted, because the change is within that +40 and the +30 was displayed last time (screenshot above).  Also, you can see that things were reordered to put the item with the most recent activity first.
[image]

However, I don't see how it reaches +14 in the first of those screenshots when the only highlighted items/changes are multiples of 10.  Is something missing there?

Comment: When did you click the indicator before that? Do you remember?

Comment: Well, essentially it means you lost some rep, that's why you see only +14 and not +50 - couldn't really find anything myself, maybe something you posted has been deleted somewhere?

Comment: Definitely within the preceding 24 hours, almost certainly within 12, and after those silver badges.

Comment: So deletions don't show in rep changes?

Comment: No, only for you and moderators. (you have to tick the "show removed posts" to see it)

Comment: 'Only for you' implies that **I** *should* see those changes in the list.  
Where is the "show removed posts" box you refer to?

Comment: In the profile page, reputation tab. The lost rep still affects the counter you mention.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a manual per-site process and it might not be clear which site the change occurred on.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Very true, those things can be real headache to catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, in the "reputation change calculator" as you call it, any reputation change, in any site you have account in on Stack Exchange, is included.

Now the question is, what can cause a reputation change?

- Upvotes you get on your own posts (not CW)
- Downvotes you cast on answers, or that you get on your own posts (not CW)
- Bounties (both you give and receive)
- Approved suggested edits
- Having answer of yours accepted, or accepting an answer (not self answer)
- Your own post that has been deleted (it can affect rep both ways)
- Post you downvoted gets deleted - gives you the 1 rep back
- User removed

You should see the reason for change for all the above except for two: your own post being deleted, or post you downvoted that was deleted. So in your speciic case, looks like something you posted and that gave you 36 reputation (e.g. question with 8 upvotes and 2 downvotes) has been deleted.

Comment: As a comment, it appears that rep changes due to users being removed also might not be included in the total.

Comment: I think they appear, but if it's a negative change it won't trigger the number highlight, which appears only upon a positive change.

Comment: I just had that happen: Since the prior check, there was a negative change from a removed user who had previously upvoted one answer, AND a positive change from one new upvote on an answer on the same site, which summed to a displayed "+10."

Comment: @WBT well, I see that in [your reputation tab](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/115786/wbt?tab=reputation), so you say it does not appear in the Achievements dialog when you open it?

Comment: The Achievements icon said +10. When I clicked it for details, it showed me two new activities: a -10 for the removed user and a +10 for the upvoted answer.  So it showed both when opening the dialog for details, but did not add them both in the total.